# How to post XML data via HTTP POST method in windows store apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

Any samples on consuming rest service post method in windows 8 apps.Please let me know  the possible links on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```csharp
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

var objHttpClient = new HttpClient();
var formParameters = "<details><id>1</id><name>test</name></details>");
var objHttpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://example.com/page");
objHttpRequestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formParameters)));
objHttpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
var result = await objHttpClient.SendAsync(objHttpRequestMessage);
```

Also check [HttpClient sample on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664)

Comment: how to write sendasync?

Comment: how to pass xml format input in above code?<details><id>1</id><name>test</name></details> like that!!!

Comment: `<details><id>1</id><name>test</name></details>`, is this your HTTP POST message ?

Comment: Update you question with exception details.

Comment: Not uploading proper to server.may be getting some exception .i don't the exact exception because in service they written failed message if the uploading is not proper.i checked the same in mozilla rest client will get sucess.in our code some problem.

Comment: getting status code 200 .but getting message like "appointment failed".The same i checked in restclient getting message like "Appoint success".Where is problem ?

Comment: Can you give me service URL & request message if it's uploaded on Internet, so I can check my self ?

Comment: Can you give me ur mail id then i will send you the url and request message.

Comment: Uri.EscapeUriString() is not needed. The XML string is a completly valid XML string compatible with text/xml.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a [System.Net.Http.StringContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent.aspx) class?

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contentString = "<details><id>1</id><name>test</name></details>";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Post,
        "http://example.com/page");
    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(
        contentString,
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "text/xml");
    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
}
```